# Error: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" when include additional php file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an issue and cannot understand what I do wrong:

- A `button` on `index.php` submit data over an `onClick.js` to `userZone.php`
- `userZone.php` will create a string array and encode as `JSON`
- `onClick.js` will show the decoded `JSON` result as alert.

This works fine until I change in `userZone.php` a simple line from:

```
//include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/engine/db.php");
```

to:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/engine/db.php");
```

-> `db.php` should include further DB connection settings but is currently an empty file.

As soon as I include the empty file `db.php`, Firebug tells me:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>   var json = JSON.parse(data);

The full project can be found here:
http://meet24.ch/StackOverFlow.zip

Comment: OK, so what does the JSON string look like?

Comment: It's a bit of a hassle to have to download that zip file to review the code. It would be better if you could select the most important lines and include them. In this case, since the error appears when you include `db.php`, you could include its contents (unless it's very large)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you saved your file as UTF8 **with** BOM.

While the beginning your file looks like, not having any char before `<?`:

```
<?
  // ####################################################################################################################
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
```

There is actually a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in front of `<?` this chars are not visible but will be parsed. As everything that is outside of the `<?   ?>` will be included into the output, the BOM will be send with the response from your server.

This will not only break JSON parsing, but also compression (when done in php) as it prevents headers from being send. In you server logs you should also see something like `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` which is cause by the BOM.

When working with php you should always make sure to save file as UTF8 **without** BOM.

Comment: There was no answer which help me to find a 100% solution but I have changed my whole project to ANSI based textfiles and use correct charset. I was struggling when using UTF-8 w/o BOM because there are troubles with notepad++ and filezilla to ensure UTF-8 w/o BOM.
Thanks to t.niese, you gave me a direction for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check '$request' - looks like it is undefined.
Try to use this:

```
 if ($_POST['request'] == 'jsonTest')
```

insteadof:

```
 if ($request == 'jsonTest')
```

Check response from ajax.

Comment: $request is definitely undefined. He could use `$_REQUEST`, but `jsonTest` is not defined anywhere so it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

The file `db.php` is not empty. Here are the non-comment contents:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1996 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

session_start();
```

The `header` calls tell the server to send specific HTML header lines. In this case, they tell the browser that the page is a HTML page, using character set UTF-8, that should not be cached.

`session_start` tells the server that you want to use the `$_SESSION` object. This function call should be the first thing you do. If you have even so little as an extra space or a UTF Byte-order marker you will get an error message: "headers already sent".

In your project, you include db.php in the file userZone.php on row 8. But before that you have sent headers. So headers get sent **twice**, once in userZone.php and once in db.php. Then you call session_start in db.php. You don't use the session variable in the project so it seems pointless. This is probably not what causes your error though. The code near the end of userZone.php doesn't work as you might expect either.

Comment: As a note: `header`  does not `[...] send specific HTML header lines[...]`. Headers are part of the HTTP protocol.